# wait for retrofit api response before return View

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, response

After receiving the Android Studio Retrofit api request, I am working on uploading the data I received from api to View.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View currentview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_following, container, false);
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    myAPI = retrofit.create(INodeJS.class);

    videosViewPager = currentview.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVideos);
    videoItems = new ArrayList<>();

    Log.d("debug Thread", "Thread Start");


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Call<String> call = myAPI.fetch_file2(i + 1);

        int finalI = i;
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                VideoItem item = new VideoItem();
                item.VideoUrl = response.body();
                videoItems.add(item);
                Log.d("response : ", String.valueOf(finalI + 1) + " /// " + response.body());
                videosViewPager.setAdapter(new VideosAdapter(videoItems));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });
    }
    
    videosViewPager.setAdapter(new VideosAdapter(videoItems));
    return currentview;
}
```

However, execute 'return currentView' before i receive all of my api response.
How can I execute return after for loop is completed (api response receiving is completed)?

Comment: Use AsyncTask class.

Comment: @ahmadbajwa As far as I know, AysncTask became deprecated. Isn't it?

Comment: Ok you can use Executors then.

Comment: I don't think you really want to block the UI thread waiting for a network response. What's wrong with updating the UI when the network request completes?

Comment: @ahmadbajwa I searched and found that network communication is not possible for execution. But my program communicates via nodejs, what should I do?

Comment: @laalto 'onResponse' will process the result after the api request, but my program's problem is to execute 'return currentView' before all for loop is finished.

Comment: So, my purpose is to make my program wait all for loop before executing 'return currentView'

Answer (score 0):

You should not hold the `currentView` till your network requests are completed, this will impact the UI thread. Instead, you should return the view and fill in the adapter once you get all the responses.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View currentview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_following, container, false);
    videosViewPager = currentview.findViewById(R.id.viewPagerVideos);
    videoItems = new ArrayList<>();

    Log.d("debug Thread", "Thread Start");
    fetchVideoItems(0);
    return currentview;
}

private void fetchVideoItems(int i) {
    Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getInstance();
    myAPI = retrofit.create(INodeJS.class);
    Call<String> call = myAPI.fetch_file2(i + 1);

    int finalI = i;
    call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                VideoItem item = new VideoItem();
                item.VideoUrl = response.body();
                videoItems.add(item);
                Log.d("response : ", String.valueOf(finalI + 1) + " /// " + response.body());

                if(i==2) // Last Iteration
                    videosViewPager.setAdapter(new VideosAdapter(videoItems));
                else {
                    fetchVideoItems(i++);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {

            }
    });

}
```